# $[] operator traversing issue mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am trying to implement the example shown for `$[]` on the [mongodb documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-all/#update-all-documents-in-an-array) under the section Update All Documents in an Array

**collection students2 with the following documents**

```
{
   "_id" : 1,
   "grades" : [
      { "grade" : 80, "mean" : 75, "std" : 8 },
      { "grade" : 85, "mean" : 90, "std" : 6 },
      { "grade" : 85, "mean" : 85, "std" : 8 }
   ]
}
{
   "_id" : 2,
   "grades" : [
      { "grade" : 90, "mean" : 75, "std" : 8 },
      { "grade" : 87, "mean" : 90, "std" : 5 },
      { "grade" : 85, "mean" : 85, "std" : 6 }
   ]
}
```

I am executing the following query using the shell (it's the same query shown in the example)

```
db.students2.update(
   { },
   { $inc: { "grades.$[].std" : -2 } },
   { multi: true }
)
```

**Error that I'm encountering**

> cannot use the part (grades of grades.$[].std) to traverse the element ({grades: [ { grade: 80, mean: 75, std: 8 }, { grade: 85, mean: 90, std: 6 }, { grade: 85, mean: 85, std: 8 } ]})

- Mongo Version : 3.6.3

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: Try  setting  [setFeatureCompatibility](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/setFeatureCompatibilityVersion/%20flag) before running update.

Comment: @Veeram thank you. this works!

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @[Veeram](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2683814/veeram), setting [setFeatureCompatibility](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/setFeatureCompatibilityVersion/) to 3.6 (depending on what version you are using) makes this work. Execute this command on admin database.